# Parsing table with beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have issues tying to parse the below html table using beautifulsoup, when i try to run that portion of my code, all i get are Nonetype errors, where essentially, print(table) = None.

What am i doing wrong?

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-striped no-background clear-padding-first-child available-slots-mobile main-table clone">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="14%" class="text-left nowrap fixed-side">Session Date</th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>1</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>2</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>3</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>4</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>5</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>6</b>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tr-border-bottom">
        <tr>
            <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                <a href="javascript:changeDate('10 Jun 2020');">10 Jun 2020</a>
                <br> Wednesday
            </th>

            <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                <a href="#" id="1217428_1_10/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">
                                                                        8:15 AM ✔
                                                                    </a>
            </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what i came up with so far, but it doesn't seem to recognise the table at all? Am i using the wrong class?

```
lesson_time = []
soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table" , {"class" : "table table-borderless table-striped"})
rows = table.findAll("tr")

for tr in rows:
    columns = rows.findAll("td")
    for td in columns:
        lesson_time.append(td.get_text())

print (lesson_time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<table class="table table-borderless table-striped no-background clear-padding-first-child available-slots-mobile main-table clone">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="14%" class="text-left nowrap fixed-side">Session Date</th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>1</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>2</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>3</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>4</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>5</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>6</b>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tr-border-bottom">
        <tr>
            <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                <a href="javascript:changeDate('10 Jun 2020');">10 Jun 2020</a>
                <br> Wednesday
            </th>

            <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                <a href="#" id="1217428_1_10/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">
                                                                        8:15 AM ✔
                                                                    </a>
            </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
target = soup.find("table", class_=re.compile("^table table-borderless"))

items = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in target.findAll(
    "td", class_="pb-15 text-center")]

print(items)
```

Output:

```
['8:15 AM ✔']
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer! unfortunately for reasons i'm not clear on, your suggestion doesn't work. could i ask if it's because my r.text has issues? (where r = a post request, instead of a get request)?

Comment: @maz `print(r.text)` and check how the class present within it !

Comment: for some reason r.text doesn't show the table at all!

but when i do not parse the table, and instead parse for href and a, there is a proper output

Comment: @maz well in this case, you were not clear enough in your question, I believe that you scraping a website where you can `inspect` the element within the browser and see it. But you wonder why that you can't `scrape` it using `BeautifulSoup`, Actually because the website which you are dealing with it is `Loaded` with `JavaScript` where `requests` module will not be able to render it ! from here i will not elaborate anymore as you've just copy/pasted the `HTML` part and came to ask but in the background you have the real issue.